# Table linked to dropbox file won't update

Tags: carto

I have a table in my cartodb account linked to a file in my public dropbox folder. I have the settings in Cartodb such that the table syncs with every hour. When I look at the table in Cartodb, it says that it is syncing fine. However, it's not actually updating the table. When I make a change in the dropbox file, Cartodb doesn't register it.

Example: right now, my table says it synced 14 minutes ago and that my table was last updated 3 hours ago. This is incorrect. I have continually been updating my table over the last three hours, the last time being about 30 min ago.

Does anyone know why Cartodb may not be recognizing when my table is updated? Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: sync and update are different - you need to set you dropbox settings http://blog.cartodb.com/post/65639747344/synced-tables-create-real-time-maps-from-data-anywhere

Comment: @Mapperz I followed the instructions in the video from the blog post you refer to, and it still doesn't work for me. When I update my spreadsheet in dropbox, dropbox recognizes the update and the link functions perfectly, but Cartodb is not recognizing the updates in dropbox and continues to sync repeatedly with the version I originally linked my table to. After three days of syncing without any registered updates, cartodb says, "Error with sync: The source is not available anymore. Please check it's location."

Comment: @Mapperz and I can't figure out any relevant settings to change in my dropbox account.

Comment: @user25917 If CartoDB says the source isn't available, double check the Dropbox URL.

Comment: @Mapperz the dropbox url still works perfectly fine, as does the file in my dropbox account. I don't know why it's not syncing correctly! Are there any special settings I might have to change in my dropbox account?

Answer (score 1):

We are fixing that problem on the platform. Dropbox made some changes in their API and we are trying to fix it, ASAP ( Hopefully in the next couple of days).

Comment: saleiva - has this been resolved? I'm still having CartoDB/Dropbox update issues.  I've not been able to get CartoDB to grab the updated file on an hourly basis as specified

Comment: hey, Can you confirm that this is working again? It should be.